# How to access sequelize instance with sequelize-typescript

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to access the sequelize instance in sequelize-typescript in order to make stored procedure calls as well as raw sql queries.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a answer to your question?

Comment: nope, I ended up switching to Golang for my next project.

Answer (score 2):

Using typedi:

```
  Container.set('sequelize', new Sequelize({...})
```

And than :

```
 const sequelize = Container.get<Sequelize>('sequelize')
```